# Remove element with JavaScript onclick and save variable in SQL

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to add a function to a web app that removes a div when a user clicks on an "x" button that is placed over the div. The web app is written in ASP.NET. I also need an SQL table value to be updated stating that the user has closed the div,so next time the user loads the page, the undesired div isn't there.The issue here is that I want this to happen WITHOUT a page reload (postback). That way I can animate the div sliding/fading away with jQuery while having the app remember that is has been closed. Here's my code so far.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:Button ID="ConCloseButton" class="CloseBut" runat="server" OnClientClick="closeConPanel();return false;;" OnClick="ConClose_Click"  Text="&#10006;" />
```

Here is my JavaScript

```
        function closeConPanel() {
            document.getElementById('con-feed').style.display = 'none';
        }
```

and here is my C# server code

```
 protected void ConClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxxxx;User ID=xxxxxx_user;Password=xxxxxxxx_user");
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("Update CookieInfo Set ConstNewsData='0' where UserEmailId='" + (Label1.Text).ToString() + "'", conn);
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["Dashboard"];
        cookie["ConstNews"] = "0";
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

So, as a summary, I would like the user to click on the ASP Button, hide the "con-feed" div, and have the app remember this (they log in with an email address, which is on the SQL table indicating their preferences. If they close a div, its state will ==0, and wont be shown. Otherwise its ==1, which will make it visible.). All of this works, but I want it to work WITHOUT a postback.

Comment: Side note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than have your ConClose_Click logic be tied to an event, just make it a page that can be invoked directly via AJAX.  Something like "RemoveDivFromDB.aspx".

Then modify your javascript method to include:

```
    function closeConPanel() {
        document.getElementById('con-feed').style.display = 'none';
        $.ajax({
              url: "/RemoveDivFromDB.aspx?id=con-feed",
              type: "get"
         });
    }
```

You can and should include a "success" and "failure"  javascript method to handle each case appropriately.  See more on the jquery site: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: How does this save the variable in the SQL table? Maybe I don't understand exactly what this method is doing. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: The logic that you have written server side to update the DB in the ConClose_Click method can be relocated to a new page.  That page doesn't even have to render HTML, you just need a URL that can handle the updating of the DB for you.  Your AJAX call can hit that URL, which will update your DB without you needing to refresh the page you are sitting on.

Comment: Awesome. Took me a while to get all the specifics down but it works. Thanks so much Bill. I wish I could increase your rep, but since I'm a new user I can't until i reach 15 rep myself. Thanks so much!